# Is there any (real-world) significance to the numbers 28:06:42:12?

Tags: donnie-darko, richard-kelly

Early in the film, [Donnie Darko](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/) wakes up after a night of sleepwalking with the numbers 28:06:42:12 written on his arm.

[image: 28:06:42:12]

I know that within the film the numbers refer to Frank telling Donnie:

> 28 days... 6 hours... 42 minutes... 12 seconds. That... is when the world... will end.

Were these numbers just made up at random by writer/director [Richard Kelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Kelly_%28director%29), or do they have some hidden meaning?

Answer (score 36):

Taken from the [IMDB trivia entry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/trivia?tab=tr&item=tr0797375) for Donnie Darko:

> The movie takes place in 1988. Frank tells Donnie the world will end
>   in 28 days, 06 hours, 42 minutes, and 12 seconds. If you add these
>   numbers, the sum is 88. When Samantha asks when she can have kids,
>   Donnie says: "Not until 8th grade." Donnie mentions to his therapist
>   that his dog Callie died when he was eight. (He is later seen holding
>   a stuffed toy dog in her office.) Donnie jokes about the Back to the
>   Future DeLorean which had a speed of 88 MPH. According to the
>   television reporter, the fire at Jim Cunningham's house was
>   extinguished "sometime after 8:00 last night." The red-eye flight that
>   almost crashes is Flight 2806 which boards at Gate 42 at 12 AM. The
>   climax of Donnie Darko occurs one week before the 1988 US presidential
>   election, when George Bush won on November 8, 1988 11/08/88. The movie
>   was shot (for a budget of less than US$5 million) in 28 days. There
>   are 28 scenes in the director's cut of this film.

[Alternately](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/trivia?tab=tr&item=tr1452510),

> Frank says the world will end in "28 days 6 hours 42 minutes 12
>   seconds." That figure is not random: it comes from adding or
>   subtracting 1 from each part of the figure 27d 7h 43m 11s, which is
>   the precise length of one lunar month (by one of the less-used
>   definitions - sidereal instead of the usual synodic).

Take away from it what you will.

Comment: *I* take from this that *Donnie Darko* was written by clairvoyants as an early tribute to Dale Earnhardt Jr.

Comment: The movie story happens in about 28 days, and the movie was shot in 28 days. So the movie was effectively shot in real time.

Comment: I think the 88 could be a reference conscient or not about the infinite loop,  each eight could refers to one of the universes: the Primary Universe and the Tangent one.

Answer (score 6):

28:06:42:12 comes from the lunar year: 27d 7h 43m 11s = 27:07:43:11 add or subtract 1 from every number.. and u get 28d 06h 42m 12s

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard of this before.  This is called a Sidereal month because it's "the time it takes the Moon to return to a given position among the stars." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_month#Sidereal_month